# random natural number from range using negative binomial

Tags: statistics, random-variables, random, negative-binomial

How can you extract a random number from a range using the negative binomial distribution?

For example:
the range of possible result values is [1,10]
the probability of success is 0.2

I really don't get it. Doesn't the distribution calculates a probability? 
How can it be used to get a real number?  I know the process should be iterative,
incrementing the number of trials, and should use the mass probability function.
I really don't know where to start.

Sorry if it's unclear.

Comment: It is a bit unclear indeed. What do you mean exactly by "extract a random number"? Do you want to program this? Also, the wikipedia page is always useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Comment: Yes I have to program this. I've looked at the wikipedia page but didn't find the answer.

Comment: Well, you simply have to make a loop that keeps track of the number of successes and then it adds a new one with probability $0.2$. When a certain limit is passed, you get out of the loop and return the number of trials. That's that ... I'm not a programming expert but this would work with small numbers at least.

Comment: In many programing languages, there are also random number generators predefined, that gives a random number according to a uniform distribution. They are not pure random, but most likely more random than what you can come up with without years to think about it and perfect the algorithms. So it might be an option to use these to get what you want.

Comment: yep i've used the standard random function of the language so far, but generating a number using the negative binomial would be closer to the real scenario i'm trying to model. Keeping the default random generator is definitely an option. Thank you